# How to deploy Juju charm in development branch

Tags: networking, juju, launchpad, bazaar, quantum

I would like to deploy this branch of the quantum-gateway juju charm

> > https://code.launchpad.net/~openstack-charmers/charms/trusty/quantum-gateway/next

resp.

> > ```
> > bzr branch lp:~openstack-charmers/charms/trusty/quantum-gateway/next
> > ```

Im able to download that source code using bzr, but what should I do next to be able to deploy it using

> > juju deploy --repository=folder local:/trusty/quantum-gateway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're dir structure looks like:

`/home/foo/charms/trusty/quantum-gateway`

and you are in `/home/foo/charms`

You would deploy using:

`juju deploy --repository=. local:trusty/quantum-gateway`

Extra:

The distro version folder name `trusty/` is important. If you are deploying a precise charm then you would need to have it named `precise/`. Another thing to note is that the folder name needs to match the name defined in the `metadata.yaml` file.